# using awk to pick up data from dynamic location

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I've compiled some code and I have tons of errors, and I want to create a table which will show few things: the path of the source file, line number, and the undefined reference to. 
The first and 2nd are not much problem to dig out using a simple awk and print $1,$2 etc, but the undefined reference is problematic since it appears in different places in the output.

Here a snippet of the error log which I'm trying to parse with a script I want to write.

```
out/target/product/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h:408: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::CopyFrom(fishy_proto::Service const&)'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp:448: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp:489: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp:489: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:279: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:319: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:319: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:722: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
out/target/product/phaedra/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h:72: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request_Type_descriptor()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:762: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:762: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:463: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:500: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:500: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:649: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:309: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:649: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:309: error: undefined reference to 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
```

As you can see, line 1 and 14 shows the undefined reference in different place compared to the other lines.

Is there a way to run an awk which would ignore the exact location but will still bring the value the undefined reference to?

Comment: Show us expected output.

Comment: oh, I just want awk to pick the undefined reference to, for example: 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample output indicates that the "undefined reference" will always be the final `awk` field of a line. In `awk`, `NF` will be the number of fields, and `$NF` will be that field whose number is "the number of fields", ie. the final field, which is what you are asking for.

```
awk '{print "undefined reference = " $NF}'
```

Comment: you're right. How to I grab the final field?

Comment: I thought the answer was clear - use `$NF` in your print statement, as shown.

Comment: the answer was edited.

Comment: If you accept the answer, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> the path of the source file, line number, and the undefined reference
>   to

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/^([^:]+):([0-9]+): error: undefined reference to (.*)/\1 \2 \3/' file
```

The output:

```
out/target/product/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h 408 'fishy_proto::Service::CopyFrom(fishy_proto::Service const&)'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp 448 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp 489 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp 489 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 51 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 51 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 51 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 51 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 51 'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 279 'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 319 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 319 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 722 'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
out/target/product/phaedra/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h 72 'fishy_proto::Request_Type_descriptor()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 762 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 762 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 463 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 500 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp 500 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h 649 'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h 309 'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h 649 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h 309 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*?):(\d+): error: undefined reference to (.*)/\1\t\2\t\3/g'
```

The output of your example would look like this:

```
out/target/product/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h    408 'fishy_proto::Service::CopyFrom(fishy_proto::Service const&)'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp   448 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp   489 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp   489 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  51  'fishy_proto::ServiceList::ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  51  'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  51  'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  51  'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  51  'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  279 'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  319 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  319 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  722 'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
out/target/product/phaedra/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h    72  'fishy_proto::Request_Type_descriptor()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  762 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  762 'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  463 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  500 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp  500 'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h   649 'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h   309 'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h   649 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h   309 'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method using sed

```
sed -ne "s/\(.*error:\)\(.*reference to \)\('.*'\)/\1\3/p" inputfile
```

Output

```
out/target/product/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h:408: error:'fishy_proto::Service::CopyFrom(fishy_proto::Service const&)'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp:448: error:'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp:489: error:'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service.cpp:489: error:'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceList::ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:51: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceList::~ServiceList()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:279: error:'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:319: error:'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:319: error:'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:722: error:'fishy_proto::Request::Request()'
out/target/product/phaedra/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libfishy_proto_intermediates/proto/base/fishy/fishy/prefix/fishy_proto/service_registry.pb.h:72: error:'fishy_proto::Request_Type_descriptor()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:762: error:'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:762: error:'fishy_proto::Request::~Request()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:463: error:'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:500: error:'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
base/fishy/fishy/impl/service_registry.cpp:500: error:'fishy_proto::Service::~Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:649: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:309: error:'fishy_proto::ServiceGroup::ServiceGroup()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:649: error:'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.h:309: error:'fishy_proto::Service::Service()'
```